# Jquery check select and input elements if filled

Tags: jquery, validation

I have this code that checks all select and input element if it is filled up. I'm getting error. Am I wrong on (':input,:select') ? Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkFields()
{
  if (!$('#lastname,#firstname,#island2,#region2,#province2,#city2,#barangay2,#address,#gender,#birthdate').filter(function () {
    return $.trim(this.value) != ""
    }).length) {
    alert("Need input");
    e.preventDefault();
    }
    else
      $('#confirm-submit').modal('show');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be just `:input` - it covers all `input`, `textarea` and `select` elements.

```
$(':input')
```

There is no selector called `:select`, instead you might have to use the element selector, the `:input` is a special selector which will cover all `input` elements like `input`, `textarea` and `select`

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery selectors in wrong way

```
if (!$(':input,:select').filter(function () {
```

should be using tag name selector like below :

```
if (!$('input,select').filter(function () {
```

And to select all input type (input, textarea, select box etc) use :

```
if (!$(':input').filter(function () {
```

For more information on [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [jQuery Input Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/).

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/214/) is here. (if condition modified and comparing it with zero)

Comment: Doesn't work :( I'm not getting any validation :( What is input:text by the way?

Comment: input:text gives you all input with type="text"

Comment: I just have input text and some select dropdown nothing more.

Comment: See my edit. I tried just the field's id and still not validating.

Comment: Somehow your if(!$('inp...) not working so need to compare it with zero ... please see http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/214/

Answer (score 0):

Select by element

```
$('input,select')
```

I'd recommend adding a required attribute and select that (in case you have other inputs that aren't required)

```
<input type="text" required />

$('input[required],select[required]')
```

Get the value

```
.val()
```

Replace all spaces with a regex (assuming you don't want a potential input to just be spaces)

```
.replace(/ /gi, '')
```

Test if there are no characters

```
.length === 0
```